# VOIP jitter on first call

Tags: voip, phone-call, jitter

In a phone system we use VOIP. There is a really big jitter which causes a robotvoice-like effect on the first call everytime I refresh the webphone. This is a big problem because refreshing happens a lot. How can I annul this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most probably a problem in the client software itself. Maybe it is choosing a too long buffer by default and then adjusts it based on first call statistics. Check if it has some maxjitter, maxaudiobufferlength or similar setting and adjust it after your needs (Or contact the developers if there is no such setting).

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I will try to inform the it department of this because I don't have acces to the settings and they appear not to be able to fix it.

Comment: Also the webphone is written in JAVA. Maybe this changes something? I mean it could be the java settings or am I mistaking?

Comment: So @Istvan making the buffer smaller and the packets smaller didn't help. It's still seriously chopped up..

Comment: It can't depend on Java settings or it is very unlikely. Also you can't make the "packets smaller". I think that it should be a bug in the software itself if it behaves like this. If you are using java then maybe worth to try the JVoIP Java library: https://www.mizu-voip.com/Software/Softphones/JVoIP.aspx